# Can I use Plotly to make animated graphs?

Tags: javascript, animation, plotly

I've come across Plotly and I am wondering whether it is possible to animate things like bar charts with it. I noticed the Streaming API but I do not think that is what I need...

Can I use JavaScript to manually do this?

Answer (score 3):

you can probably check out the [postMessage API](https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API) here.

Answer (score 2):

Animations were just released in in Plotly.js. Docs are here: https://plot.ly/javascript/animations/

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes you can animate bar charts made with Plotly. Plotly has an [open-source JS library](https://plot.ly/javascript/) built on top of D3 which should make it very easy for you to create your own animated bar charts. You could also just [use D3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3) instead of Plotly.